# What the best way to handle long query strings in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm working on an application that will potentially have very long query strings to maintain state.

I'm not sure what the best way to handle these long query strings in the action methods, since  I will end up with a very long list of parameters.

Is it best to access the query string parameters directly from the request object or should I go ahead and create an action method with a very long parameter list?

i.e. a number a configuration parameters need to be passed in to customise the page. so we might have a query string as such: ?rid=123&bid=456&cid=789&did=aaa&bg=333&f=999&.....

```
        public ActionResult AvailableTimes(int rid, int bid, int cid, string did, string bg, string f......)
        {
          // Do stuff
        }
```

or

```
public ActionResult AvailableTimes()
        {
          var query = Request.Query;
          // Do stuff
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best option is probably to move the query string data somewhere else, like Session or Profile.

Comment: Give us an example of what you may encounter...

Comment: @edmastermind29 have updated post with example

Comment: @jrummell we really want to avoid using sessions and no need for user to log in to use the site

Comment: You can access Session without a logged in user.

Comment: @jrummell I am aware of this we just want to avoid using sessions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an class that contains all parameters of your query string. Then in your action result, use the object instead of all the parameters.

```
public ActionResult AvailableTimes(TimeItem time)
        {
          // Do stuff with time
        }
public Class TimeItem
{
    int rid { get; set; }
    int bid { get; set; }
    int cid { get; set; }
    string did { get; set; }
    string bg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: unless you are using FormMethod.Post, this will still result in a long query string. In fact, it will be longer because the variables will be TimeItem.rid, TimeItem.bid, TimeItem.cid, etc.

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus No they won't be any longer.  If TimeItem was a property of some other object then yes, but MVC is smart enough to map to "rid" and all the others with the short name.  I agree that this is a better way to handle an Action with a large number of inputs.

Comment: @Kleinux I probably should have been more clear: If TimeItem is the Model type then you'll get short names, but if it's a sub-item of the model (for instance MyDisplayModel.FilterModel) it will be the long names. I just ran into this, but rather than use GET for the form, I used the Post-Redirect-Get pattern: temporarily caching the posted model in TempData (could store in Session or database also) with a key, and then redirecting to a get-friendly URL (with just that ID of the cached instance in the case of persisting).

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus if the form is based off of a sub-item of the view model, then the post method parameter object would be that sub object. EG:
`MyDisplayPost(FilterModel form)
{
    //do stuff with form
    var model = new MyDisplayModel();
    model.FilterModel = form;
    //do redirect with model
}`
this would accept the short named form inputs and still return the proper model to the view. now if the form was based off of the MyDisplayModel, and returned values in FilterModel, then yes, the names would be longer.